# Unable to run named placeholder for order by ASC in php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am new to **PHP PDO** and trying to use named placeholder at the place of ORDER BY *ASC*. Sometime in simple query page this run very successfully but unable to run in the following query:

**PHP CODE IS:**

```
$price_sort = "ASC";
$keyword = "samsung glaxy";
$limit = 0;
    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT *, MATCH(title) against (:keyword) as 'relevence'
                FROM view_store_items_grid 
                WHERE MATCH(title) against(:keyword) 
                ORDER BY relevence DESC, price :order
                LIMIT :limit,25");
    $query->bindValue(":keyword",$keyword);
    $query->bindValue(":order",$price_sort);
    $query->bindValue(":limit", $limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $query->execute();
```

When I remove placeholder `:order` with `ASC` this run and gives result but when I use this placeholder, I get empty result.

For Fetching data or to show fetched result I am using

```
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) :
       extract($row);
       echo "$name";
endwhile;
```

What I am doing wrong and How I can use many *named placeholder* in query at different places?

Comment: you cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in a prepared statement

Comment: You mean I should use two different placeholder at the place of `:keyword` ?

Comment: Try using different placeholder of `keyword`

Comment: I replaced `keyword` with `keyword_order` but this also does not solved my problem.

Comment: Have you add  `bindValue` of `keyword_order`

Comment: Yes `$query->bindValue(":keyword_order",$keyword);` and replaced it with second paramater `keyword`

Comment: when I remove `:order` with ASC. It runs

Comment: You can't bind DML. In this case you'll need to choose from a whitelist of `"asc", "desc"` and then concatenate that into the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not bind ASC/DESC in prepared statement. Parameters are automatically quoted, and ASC/DESC shouldn't be quoted. this is the same reason that table and column names can't be parameters.

Instead you can do like that

```
$sql_query = "SELECT *, MATCH(title) against (:keyword) as 'relevence'
                FROM view_store_items_grid 
                WHERE MATCH(title) against(:keyword) 
                ORDER BY relevence DESC, price "
if($price_order == 'ASC'){
    $sql_query .= " ASC "
}else{
    $sql_query .= " DESC  "
}
$sql_query .= " LIMIT :limit,25  "
$query = $db->prepare($sql_query);
```

Refer [How bindValue in LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269840/how-bindvalue-in-limit)

Refer [pdo binding asc/desc order dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690297/pdo-binding-asc-desc-order-dynamically)

Also do not try to use the same named parameter twice in a single SQL statement, for example

```
<?php 
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE  some_value > :value OR some_value < :value'; 
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->execute( array( ':value' => 3 ) ); 
?>
```

...this will return no rows and no error -- you must use each parameter once and only once. Apparently this is expected behavior (according to this bug report: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=33886)  because of portability issues.

Comment: Yes. according to you, when I replace with `ASC` then it runs. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Hello Tamil, how you going? I got one similar question about PDO Limit Placeholders, is it possible to use the named placeholder to Limit inside the execute?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72081221/error-to-selecet-when-use-pdo-prepared-limit?noredirect=1#comment127363151_72081221

Answer (score 0):

This one solved this question by replacing the `price_sort` variable value with `price ASC` and removing the `price` before the placehoder `:order`

as:

`$price_sort = "price ASC";`

and the query is as:

```
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT *, MATCH(title) against (:keyword) as 'relevence'
                FROM view_store_items_grid 
                WHERE MATCH(title) against(:keyword) 
                ORDER BY relevence DESC, :order
                LIMIT :limit,25");
```

this solved my question with the help of answer of @tamil

Thank you